# redirect on subfolder with more domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a sub folder `/blog` hosting my blog and the root hosting the application. I have couple of domains which are targeting my root. I would like to redirect with .htaccees all the request on sub folder blog to given domain

```
domain1
domain2
domain3
```

each touching root

if request

```
domain1/blog

domain2/blog
```

than redirect to `domain3/blog`

What I try

```
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}  domain\.de(.*)|domain1\.de(.*)|domain2\.com(.*)|domain3\.de(.*)
RewriteRule  (.*)  http\://www\.domain4\.com/blog/$1 [R=301]



<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !domain4\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://www.domain4/blog/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could just invert the condition using a `!`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !domain4\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain4.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you for feedback I just gave  try with your snippet but won't redirect

Comment: @fefe if your htaccess file is **in your `blog` folder**, then you need to remove the "blog" part of the regex pattern.

Comment: yeah but I use 2 htaccess this one needed for wordpress rewrites

Comment: Sorry I saw a bit to late what u mean